# Nativescript, iOS, setting image as background in CSS not working

Tags: css, nativescript, nativescript-angular

In my nativescript application I want to set an image as a background with

`background-image: url("res://ic_more")`

It works on Android, but not on iOS.

This image exists in App_Resources/iOS folder:

[image]

And I can even use it in `Image` like this (red arrow):

`<Image src="res://ic_more"></Image>`

[image]

The problem is somewhere in CSS I believe.

Already tried:
`tns platform clean ios`

Will appreciate any help

Comment: Can you share the Layout / View on which you are applying this background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for set background image in android and iOS both.

```
<DockLayout stretchLastChild="false">
   <GridLayout rows="*,*" class="page" backgroundImage="~/app/images/home_bg.jpg" backgroundRepeat="no-repeat" backgroundSize="cover" backgroundPosition="center"> 
   </GridLayout>
</DockLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. The problem was in incorrect background positioning.